# Segmentation Fault core dumped C++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

not sure why i am getting segmentation fault for this particular line of code, i know you get that error when you are trying to access a part of memory that you don't have access to but i cant figure out what is wrong.

i am trying to change between scene, and by putting the function that pushes the object in vector i get Segmentation fault (core dumped)
, this only happen when i push the sphere and plane, when i comment those 2 line out it works but then it won't render the sphere of course..
any ideas?
it also works if i remove the "if statement"
thank you.

```
vector < Source * > lightSource;
vector < Object * > sceneObjects;

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    if (firstScene) {
        Sphere sphereScene(sphere, .825, green_ref);
        Plane planeScene(plane[0][0], plane[0][1], -1, maroon);
        Light lightScene(light, whiteLight);

        ////////////this is what is causing problem i think//////////////////
        sceneObjects.push_back(dynamic_cast < Object * > ( & sphereScene));
        sceneObjects.push_back(dynamic_cast < Object * > ( & planeScene));
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        lightSource.push_back(dynamic_cast < Source * > ( & lightScene));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            sceneObjects.push_back(new Triangle(pyramidCoord[i], Blue));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            sceneObjects.push_back(new Triangle(ceiling[i], White));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            sceneObjects.push_back(new Triangle(wallG[i], Green));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            sceneObjects.push_back(new Triangle(wallR[i], Red));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            sceneObjects.push_back(new Triangle(floor1[i], White));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to read the code snippet - appears to be missing brace(s). If the indentation is right, the Sphere, Plane and Light objects lifetime ends after the if block. But dangling pointers to that now undefined memory are stored in the sceneObjects list and might be accessed later (and crash). Why not use new like Triangle?

Comment: good point i changed it to this                        sceneObjects.push_back(new   Sphere(sphere,.825,green_ref));
      sceneObjects.push_back(new Sphere(plane[0][0],plane[0][1], -1, m    aroon));
      lightSource.push_back(new Light(light,whiteLight)); not i am getting diffrent error but its not segmentation fault anymore

Comment: Yay! Next time it is important to post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (MVCE) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we don't have to guess. Now, on to your next problem ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pushing the address of a local stack-based variable into a container that you later add dynamically allocated objects to.  You're probably referencing the local (`sphereScene`, `planeScene`) after those variables have been destroyed.  Cleaning up the memory for all those allocated Triangles is a problem, too, since you can't delete the memory for the locals.

Assuming `Object` is a base of `Sphere` et al, you shouldn't need the `dynamic_cast` to store the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it

```
sceneObjects.push_back(new Sphere(sphere,.825,green_ref));
sceneObjects.push_back(new Sphere(plane[0][0],plane[0][1], -1, maroon));
lightSource.push_back(new Light(light,whiteLight));
```

but now i am getting another error

error: no matching function for call to ‘Sphere::Sphere(glm::vec3&, glm::vec3&, int, Color&)’
       sceneObjects.push_back(new Sphere(plane[0][0],plane[0][1], -1, maroon));

this is how my function definition looks like in sphere.h

```
#ifndef SPHERE
#define SPHERE


class Sphere : public Object {
    vec3 center;
    double radius;
    Color color;

public:
    Sphere();
    Sphere(vec3, double, Color);
};


Sphere::Sphere()
{
    vec3 center(0,0,0);
    radius=1.0;
    color= Color(0.5,0.5,0.5,0);
}

Sphere::Sphere(vec3 centerV, double radiusV, Color colorV)
    {
        center=centerV;
        radius=radiusV;
        color=colorV;
    }


#endif // SPHERE
```

Comment: The function prototype has references (`glm::vec3 &`) , while the function definition does not (`vec3`).

Comment: never mind i was pushing Sphere two time instead of pushing plane. consider this question closed thank you all.